# List of simple arrays with pyplot.plot

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have some trouble to understand how `pyplot.plot` works.
I take a simple example: I want to plot `pyplot.plot(lst2, lst2)` where lst2 is a list.
The difficulty comes from the fact that each element of lst2 is an array of shape (1,1). If the elements were floating and not array, there would be no problems.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

V2 = np.array([[1]])
W2 = np.array([[2]])

print('The shape of V2 is', V2.shape)
print('The shape of W2 is', W2.shape)

lst2 = [V2, W2]
plt.plot(lst2, lst2)
plt.show
```

Below is the end of the error message I got:

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _xy_from_xy(self,x, y)
    245         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:
    246             raise ValueError("x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have "
--> 247                              "shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))
    248 
    249         if x.ndim == 1:

ValueError: x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have shapes (2, 1, 1) and (2, 1, 1)
```

What surprised me in the error message is the mention of an array of dimension (2,1,1). It seems like the array `np.array([V2,W2])` is built when we call `pyplot.plot`.

My question is then what happens behind the scenes when we call pyplot.plot(x,y) with x and y list? It seems like an array with the elements of x is built (and same for y). And these arrays must have maximum 2 axis. Am I correct?

I know that if I use numpy.squeeze on V2 and W2, it would work. But I would like to understand what it happening inside `pyplot.plot` in the example I gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a closer look at what you're doing:

```
V2 = np.array([[1]])
W2 = np.array([[2]])
lst2 = [V2, W2]
plt.plot(lst2, lst2)
```

For some odd reason you're defining your arrays to be of shape `(1,1)` by using a nested pair of brackets. When you construct `lst2`, you stack your arrays along *a new leading dimension*. This has nothing do with pyplot, this is numpy.

Numpy arrays are rectangular, and they are compatible with lists of lists of ... of lists. The level of nesting determines the number of dimensions of an array. Look at a simple 2d example:

```
>>> M = np.arange(2*3).reshape(2,3)
>>> print(repr(M))
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

You can for all intents and purposes think of this 2x3 matrix as two row vectors. `M[0]` is the same as `M[0,:]` and is the first row, `M[1]` is the same as `M[1,:]` is the second row. You could then also construct this array from the two rows in the following way:

```
row1 = [0, 1, 2]
row2 = [3, 4, 5]
lst = [row1, row2]
np.array(lst)
```

My point is that we took two flat lists of length 3 (which are compatible with 1d numpy arrays of shape `(3,)`), and concatenated them in a list. The result was compatible with a 2d array of shape `(2,3)`. The "2" is due to the fact that we put 2 lists into `lst`, and the "3" is due to the fact that both lists had a length of 3.

So, when you create `lst2` above, you're doing something that is equivalent to this:

```
lst2 = [ [[1]], [[2]] ]
```

You put two nested sublists into an array-compatible list, and both sublists are compatible with shape `(1,1)`. This implies that you'll end up with a 3d array (in accordance with the fact that you have three opening brackets at the deepest level of nesting), with shape `(2,1,1)`. Again the 2 comes from the fact that you have two arrays inside, and the trailing dimensions come from the contents.

---

The real question is what you're trying to do. For one, your data shouldn't really be of shape (1,1). In the most straightforward application of `pyplot.plot` you have 1d datasets: one for the x and one for the y coordinates of your plot. For this you can use a simple (flat) list or 1d array for both x and y. What matters is that they are of the same length.

Then when you plot the two against each other, you pass the x coordinates first, then the y coordinates second. You presumably meant something like

```
plt.plot(V2,W2)
```

In which case you'd pass 2d arrays to plot, and you wouldn't see the error caused by passing a 3d-array-like. However, the behaviour of [`pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) is non-trivial for 2d inputs (columns of both datasets will get plotted against one another), and you have to make sure that you really want to pass 2d arrays as inputs. But you almost never want to pass the same object as the first two arguments to `pyplot.plot`.

Comment: The reason I was asking this question is because when you do np.dot (A,B) with A of shape (1,n) and B of shape (n,1), you will get an array of shape (1,1) and not a floating unfortunately.  I was doing a loop in which for each iteration I was computing this kind of matrix product and I was putting the result at the end of a list with the function append. At the end, I had a list of shape (number_iter, 1,1) instead of having a simple list of floating.  And I could not plot the list.

Comment: @S.Tim thanks for the feedback. You should probably not have those "linear 2d arrays" to begin with. Are you using the `np.matrix` class? You should use `ndarray`s instead, they're much more convenient. And would it have been possible to compute each iteration in parallel? In that case you could do much better (in terms of performance) than looping, you could compute all the dot products at once.